# Why are some lines in the title not included in the line number?

Tags: line-numbering, author, lineno

for example：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}

\title{My Title}
\author{%
  Author One$^1$ \\ Author Two$^2$ 
  \\
    \normalsize{$^1$Organization 1}\\
    \normalsize{$^2$Organization 2}\\
    \\
    \normalsize{Emails: 111@mail.com, 222@mail.com}\\
  }
\date{}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

output：

[image]

You can see that there are many lines that are not marked with line numbers. I want to know the reason.

Comment: \parbox and minipage also count as one line each.

Comment: Off-topic: `\normalsize` is a switch and does *not* take an argument. Hence, instead of `\normalsize{$^1$Organization 1}`, you may want to write `{\normalsize $^1$Organization 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the reason.

The `article` document class (cf. the file `article.cls`) typesets the author block, i.e., the argument of the `\author` macro -- as the contents of a top-aligned single-column `tabular` environment:

```
    {\large
      \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
         \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
```

An outside package such as `lineno` doesn't have the means to "peek" inside this `tabular` environment to determine how many rows may be inside. To the `lineno` package, the entire `tabular` environment looks like a (rather tall) monolith. That's why just one line number is assigned to the entire author block.